# Generate liquibase changelog from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, url, liquibase, changelog

I have a SQL Server database and want to generate a liquibase changelog via command line like this:

```
.\liquibase `
--driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver `
--classpath=C:\Users/Ferid/Downloads/MicrosoftJDBCDriver6.0forSQLServer/sqljdbc_6.0/deu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar `
--changeLogFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\sdk\workspace\changelog\com\example\newChangelogMSSQLX.xml" `
--url="jdbc:sqlserver://ferdects.database.windows.net:1433;db8" `
--username=username `
--password=password `
generateChangeLog
```

but when I execute it this error occurs:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value db8: parameters must start with a '--'

SEVERE 8/8/18 11:54 AM: liquibase: Unexpected value db8: parameters must start with a '--'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unexpected value db8: parameters must start with a '--'
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:774)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:133)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I have tried several syntaxes for the url but none of them did work. My database's name is db8 and I am using SQL Server 2017 and liquibase-3.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think your URL should be

`--url="jdbc:sqlserver://ferdects.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db8"`

Comment: I have tried that too but then this error occurs: 
`Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not parse '--url'

SEVERE 8/8/18 5:57 PM: liquibase: Could not parse '--url'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Could not parse '--url'
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.splitArg(Main.java:783)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:739)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:133)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103) `

Comment: What version of liquibase are you using? Might have to dig into the source to see what it is doing.

Comment: I'm also thinking that something else strange may be going on - I see that you are using linux-style commands (`.\liquibase`) but Windows-style paths (some with backslashes, some with forward slashes). Also, some things with quotes and some without. So this may be more to do with shell stuff than with liquibase. One thing to try is to edit the liquibase.bat file to show the exact command that is being passed along to java.

Comment: I am using windows but since Windows PowerShell suggested me to use `.\ ` I have did it like that. Now I have edited it so that all slashes and quotes have the same style but still nothing changed

Comment: Do you mean this command? `IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_OPTS set JAVA_OPTS=

java -cp "%CP%" %JAVA_OPTS% liquibase.integration.commandline.Main %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I've never run liquibase from PowerShell, so it could be that PowerShell is doing something in there too. Echoing the actual command before running it is sometimes helpful. 
Something line this:
`set  _cmd=(whatever the cmd is, in this case the java... line)`
`echo %_cmd%`
`%_cmd%`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows use the ^ instead of `